# Combinatorica package and graph-theoretical issues

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've searched for a solution to my problem a couple of days, and I didn't find one. Hope you guys can help me.

I'm currently trying to solve some graph-theoretical problems. One of them is to find the maximum flow throughout a graph. I've managed to draw the graph in *Mathematica*, and would now like to use the built-in function `NetworkFlow`. To do this I need to load the package `Combinatorica`, but that gives me problems with "shadowed" functions. I've tried to refer to them by their fully qualified names, e.g., `Combinatorica```NetworkFlow`, etc., but I still can't get it to work.

I've pasted in some code which I hope will make it easier to see what I'm doing wrong:

```
Graph[{Kø -> Ro, Kø -> Pu, Kø -> Pa, Ro -> Ha, Ro -> Be, Pu -> Ha, 
  Pu -> Be, Pa -> Ha, Ha -> Be, Ha -> St, Ha -> Br, Ha -> Li, 
  Be -> St, Be -> Br, Be -> Li, St -> Br, St -> Li, St -> Par, 
  Br -> Li, Br -> Par, Li -> Par}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {"2", "11", "8", "3", "5", "14", "11", "10", "12", 
   "12", "10", "10", "4", "4", "12", "4", "12", "11", "23", "16", 
   "10"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, 
 GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which gives me a nice graph. Below is the "real" problem:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Graph[{Kø -> Ro, Kø -> Pu, Kø -> Pa, Ro -> Ha, Ro -> Be, Pu -> Ha, 
  Pu -> Be, Pa -> Ha, Ha -> Be, Ha -> St, Ha -> Br, Ha -> Li, 
  Be -> St, Be -> Br, Be -> Li, St -> Br, St -> Li, St -> Par, 
  Br -> Li, Br -> Par, Li -> Par}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {"2", "11", "8", "3", "5", "14", "11", "10", "12", 
   "12", "10", "10", "4", "4", "12", "4", "12", "11", "23", "16", 
   "10"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, 
 GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
Combinatorica`NetworkFlow[%, Kø, Par]
```

> During evaluation of In[28]:= General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded
>   functionaliy. The package now being loaded may conflict with this.
>   Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.

```
Out[29]= Graph({Kø->Ro,Kø->Pu,Kø->Pa,Ro->Ha,Ro->Be,Pu->Ha,Pu->Be,Pa->Ha,Ha->Be,Ha->St,Ha->Br,Ha->Li,Be->St,Be->Br,Be->Li,St->Br,St->Li,St->Par,Br->Li,Br->Par,Li->Par},EdgeWeight->{2,11,8,3,5,14,11,10,12,12,10,10,4,4,12,4,12,11,23,16,10},VertexLabels->Name,ImagePadding->10,GraphLayout->SpringEmbedding)

Out[30]= NetworkFlow(Graph({Kø->Ro,Kø->Pu,Kø->Pa,Ro->Ha,Ro->Be,Pu->Ha,Pu->Be,Pa->Ha,Ha->Be,Ha->St,Ha->Br,Ha->Li,Be->St,Be->Br,Be->Li,St->Br,St->Li,St->Par,Br->Li,Br->Par,Li->Par},EdgeWeight->{2,11,8,3,5,14,11,10,12,12,10,10,4,4,12,4,12,11,23,16,10},VertexLabels->Name,ImagePadding->10,GraphLayout->SpringEmbedding),Kø,Par)
```

Comment: I am curious - what is background of this problem? - could you enlighten us please?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need the package if you have Mathematica 9. Something very important - you cannot use strings on `EdgeWeight` - you need numerical values there. So corrected your code is:

```
g = Graph[{Kø -> Ro, Kø -> Pu, Kø -> Pa, Ro -> Ha, Ro -> Be, Pu -> Ha,
    Pu -> Be, Pa -> Ha, Ha -> Be, Ha -> St, Ha -> Br, Ha -> Li, 
   Be -> St, Be -> Br, Be -> Li, St -> Br, St -> Li, St -> Par, 
   Br -> Li, Br -> Par, Li -> Par}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {2, 11, 8, 3, 5, 14, 11, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10, 4, 4, 12,
     4, 12, 11, 23, 16, 10}, ImagePadding -> 10, 
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]

Edge labels are edge weights. For the flow we do:

```
OF = FindMaximumFlow[g, Kø, Par, "OptimumFlowData", EdgeCapacity -> EdgeWeight];

OF["FlowValue"]
```

> 21

```
SetProperty[OF["FlowGraph"], {EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 13],
 EdgeLabels -> (# -> Row[{OF[#], "/", 
 PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight]}] & /@ EdgeList[g])}]
```

[image]

Now you have "edge flow / edge capacity". Edge opacity is also edge flow. There is a free trial version of Mathematica 9 if you do not have it yet.

Comment: I'm having some trouble installing the new version 9.0, but your answer was perfect - exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. I need to use it for a new class I'm taking. My teacher want me to calculate it by hand, so I need something to check my answers!

Comment: @MarcoDalFarra I am curious - what is background of this problem? - could you explain please? Some sort of chemical processes?

Comment: The Vertexes represent major cities in europe, eg. Kø = København, danish for Copenhagen, Par = Paris, etc. So I need to figure out how to move max passengers from Copenhagen to Paris given a railroad capacity between each city.

Answer (score 3):

Precede Graph with the `` System` `` context and it should work out fine. Please note that you can't use system 8 Graphs as input in Combinatorica graph functions. They have to be converted first, for instance by converting the v8 Graph to an adjacency matrix, which can be converted to a Combinatorica graph.

```
ShowGraph[SpringEmbedding@FromAdjacencyMatrix[ AdjacencyMatrix@g // Normal]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You lose the labels in the process.